# displaying report

Tags: mysql

Please can someone help me with this.

I am doing a payroll system and I am stuck in between. I want to select informations from two tables, this are my table structure:

**`employee_tbl`** table:

```
user_id,
emp_id,
surname,
firstname,
email_address,
dob,
gender,
phone_number,
home_address,
appointment_date,
nationality,
gross_salary,
emp_date,
status
```

**`other_allowance`** table:

```
allo_id, 
user_id, 
month_salary, 
feeding_allowance, 
outstation_allowance, 
leave_allowance, 
total_overtime, 
allo_date,
```

What I want is to display (`employee_name`, `feeding allowance`, `leave allowance`, `outstation allowance`)

**Note:** It would display all employee(s) from the employee table and then put the allowances of those that have allowance for that particular month in front of their name e.g displays all employees but put allowances in front of an employee that has allowance(s) for the month of lets say march 2013.

this is my own query:

SELECT * FROM employee_tbl JOIN other_allowance WHERE month_salary = '3.2013'

but its displaying each employee 3times.

Can someone please explain what you think I should do, I would really appreciate.

Comment: Instead of just nameing all the columns, please do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables and put that. I think your date field is varchar.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that giving you ready query is good for you, so here's the direction. You should use JOIN operator in your query. Take a look at this article [MySQL JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM employee_tbl e
JOIN other_allowance a ON e.user_id = a.user_id
WHERE month_salary = 'xxxx'
```